# Как правильно перевести string в List?

Tags: c#, строки, list

Как такого вида строку:

```
"[ [ [1],[2],[3] ], [ [4],[5],[6]] ]"
```

перевести в список такого же вида?

Comment: Вам нужен парсер, разбор JSON руками  делать я бы не советовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если строка всегда в таком формате, то можно использовать регулярное выражение. 
Например, так:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...
var s = "[ [ [1],[2],[3] ], [ [4],[5],[6]] ]";
var lst = Regex.Matches(s, "\\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(";", lst));   // 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

А если строка бывает разной (и судя по всему это JSON), то надо использовать JSON-парсер, например [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) -- входит в Microsoft Azure SDK (в сборке Newtonsoft.Json.dll), его также можно скачать как отдельный пакет с [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).